# Block a user after a specified number of failed logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In our application we want to block a user after a specified number of failed logins. We are using custom tables to store a user.

In our login page it contains three fields like user name, password and an id field. The id field is not unique.

So how can i block a user, if i will use the user name to calculate the failed attempts, so another person can easily block the account by just guessing the user name and typing it wrongly.

So what is the best method to get the failed logins and there by block the user?

Comment: Why do you want to block a user account instead of blocking IP of attacker?

Comment: @zerkms: its like a requirement from client to block the user and then they have to ask admin to unblock the account..

Comment: To detect if somebody making attempt to log in is the one of the reason lockout policy is used. If you will lock ONLY for the actual user, then what's the point of using lockout policy?

Comment: @Kai: yes correct .. so can you please suggest a way to detect the login attempt of spam user.

Comment: @mahesh: the best way is to ban by IP the attacker, not the poor user

Comment: @zerkms: i am not sure i understand that, can you please elaborate it. So do we need to get a set of acceptable ips before starting.?

Comment: @mahesh: no. But to ban a user account just because of a bruteforce by an attacker is barely a good solution

Comment: @zerkms: so if a user forgot his password and try to login by guessing his password is like a brute force attack. So in that case also we will block that user. i think its a right method?

Comment: @mahesh: doesn't matter what caused a bruteforce. To ban an attacker (by ip) is a common and good solution, to ban a user account - nope

Answer (score 1):

I would use a FailedAttemptCount column in your user table, and just increment it every time the user's attempt is invalid

Comment: yes thats what i am doing now, but in this case a second user know the username can easily block the user, thats my concern..

Comment: But that is always the case. If I know someone's login name to, say Active Directory, I can easily get their account locked out just be typing invalid passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)?  This already handles the situations you've mentioned.  This can be configured to lock an account after a number of failed attempts.

In a situation such as membership (I assume you're also storing passwords) I would suggest using an already created system instead of rolling your own.

Comment: but we are using custom tables for login not any .net membership.

Comment: I understand.  I'm just suggesting you use the .net membership provider; it's easier, and safer.  The .net membership already handles failed log-ins, forgot password, roles, salting+hashing passwords, multi-tenancy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Asp.NET Membership provider you can configure the provider to have login attempts, `maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"`{any attempt number}.For more see [Login Attempts](http://forums.asp.net/t/1622750.aspx)

Comment: but we are using custom tables for login not any .net membership.

Comment: well you may have to write your own code logic which may be similar to Asp.NET Membership provider. However I don't think it is necessary to do so, because there is out of the box provided by .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

On a failed login attempt, I would use a dictionary stored in Application State, with the IP as `key` and a simple integer to count the attemts as `value`

Then on each failed login, if the user's IP exists in the dictionary, increase it. If the attempt counter is `>` than the number of login attemts, abort the session.

Of course, you would need to also implement a time interval, and a way to reset the counter on a succesfull login.

But that should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a couple of columns to your user table to track the number of failed logins.   You can then update the number of failed logins each time someone puts in the wrong credentials, and if they put in the right credentials you can set it back to 0.

You could also add a datetime field for the last login attempt if you want to specify a timeout of half an hour for example.

Comment: yes thats what i am doing now, but in this case a second user know the username can easily block the user, thats my concern..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  The SessionID is useful , if the same SessionID and the same user name login three

times  when the login fails , the user with the sessionID is Blocked....

Comment: but in this case if a user closes the current session and if try to login then he can try to login for 3 times. but this has to be avoided.

Comment: @mahesh  We can identify a user by getting a number from the database when its first login and save the number to cookie.

Comment: we can caculate the failed logins by username and the database-generated number